# Unit Test unwind segue with calculated returned value

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

I am creating an unit-test to test value which is back from second ViewController.
**Program flow :** 
1. FirstVC got clicked and then pass number 200 to SecondVC.
2. SecondVC received number and increment it by 1.
3. SecondVC got clicked on "Back" button. It sends back 201 to FirstVC.

**FirstVC :**

```
import UIKit

class FirstVC: UIViewController {

    var number : Int?;
    var destVC : SecondVC?;

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        number = 200;
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func hitButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("goNext", sender: self);
    }
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let svc = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondVC;
        svc.receivedNumber = self.number;
        self.destVC = svc
    }
    @IBAction func backToFirstVC(segue: UIStoryboardSegue){
        if(segue.identifier == "backSegue"){
            let srcVC = segue.sourceViewController as! SecondVC;
            self.number = srcVC.receivedNumber;
            print(self.number);
        }
    }
}
```

**SecondVC.swift :**

```
import UIKit

class SecondVC: UIViewController {
var receivedNumber : Int?;
@IBOutlet weak var numberLbl: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.receivedNumber = self.receivedNumber! + 1;
    self.numberLbl.text = String(self.receivedNumber!);
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func hitBackBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("backSegue", sender: self);
}
}
```

**FirstVCTests.swift :**

```
import XCTest
@testable import practiceTesting

class practiceTestingTests: XCTestCase {

    var firstVC :practiceTesting.FirstVC!
    var storyboard : UIStoryboard!;
    var storyboardsegue : UIStoryboardSegue!;

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        firstVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstVC") as! practiceTesting.FirstVC;
        _ = firstVC.view;
    }

    func testExample() {
        firstVC.hitButton(self);
        firstVC.destVC!.hitBackBtn(self);
        XCTAssertEqual(firstVC.number, 201)
    }
}
```

**Error Message :**
XCTAssertEqual failed: ("Optional(200)") is not equal to ("Optional(201)")

It seems like `.hitButton()` does not finish the job yet, but `XCTAssertEqual()` simultaneoulsy do the assert task.

How can I let `.hitButton()` wait the calculation from `secondVC` and then assert the returned value?

**Update :** 
I will be back for my topic again, for now. I will test just a function.

```
import XCTest

@testable import practiceTesting

class FirstVCTests: XCTestCase {

    var firstVC :practiceTesting.FirstVC!
    var secondVC:practiceTesting.SecondVC!
    var storyboard : UIStoryboard!;
    var segue1 : UIStoryboardSegue!;
    var segue2 : UIStoryboardSegue!;

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);
        firstVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstVC") as! practiceTesting.FirstVC;
        secondVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondVC") as! practiceTesting.SecondVC;
        segue1 = UIStoryboardSegue.init(identifier: "goNext", source: firstVC, destination: secondVC)
        segue2 = UIStoryboardSegue.init(identifier: "backSegue", source: secondVC, destination: firstVC);
        _ = firstVC.view;
    }

    func testB(){
        secondVC.receivedNumber = 300;
        firstVC.backToFirstVC(segue2);                    
        XCTAssertEqual(firstVC.number, 300);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unwind segue will create a new `firstVC` after performed. You should get the real `firstVC` in `SecondVC`'s `prepareForSegue`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't know how to do that. If you know please guide me to the solution. Either URLs or keywords are fine.